# How can I check to see if a user doesn't gave a role?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I currently have a check that only runs a command if the command author has a specific role. I'd like it to do the opposite, where it would only run a command if the user DOESN'T have the role. However, I'm not sure how I would go about writing this in my check.

Current check:

```py
async def blacklisted(ctx):
    blrole = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=blacklistrole)
    return blrole in ctx.author.roles
```

Comment: Try putting not before in, like this:

return blrole not in ctx.author.roles

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could help you:

```
async def blacklisted(ctx):
    blrole = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=blacklistrole)
    return blrole not in ctx.author.roles
```